# Julia UndefVarError on Metaprogramming

Tags: julia

I'm trying to do a solver for equations. When I run the code the `X` variable appears to be undefined, but it prints out perfectly. What am I missing?
I should give the program some numbers, than operations as Macros and it should create an outer product matrix of the operations applied.

```
function msu()
    print("Insert how many values: ")
    quantity = parse(Int64, readline())
    values = []
    for i in 1:quantity
        println("x$i")
        num1 = parse(Float64, readline())
        push!(values, num1)
    end

    println(values)

    print("How many operations? ")
    quantity = parse(Int64, readline())
    ops = []
    for i in 1:quantity
        push!(ops, Meta.parse(readline()))
    end

    mat = zeros((quantity, quantity))

    for i in 1:length(mat)
        sum = 0
        for j in 1:length(values)
            # here begins problems, the following prints are for debugging purpose
            print(length(values))
            func = Meta.parse("$(ops[convert(Int64, ceil(j / quantity))]) * $(ops[convert(Int64, j % quantity)])")
            print(func)
            x = values[j]
            println(x)
            sum += eval(func)
        end

        mat[i] = sum
    end

    println(mat)
end

msu()
```

The original code was in Spanish, if you find any typo it's probably because I skipped a translation.

Comment: Clarification question: what makes you say that `x` is undefined?